# Wrong Column Name Used By Spring Data/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

It started as a problem in my Table model class, and I was able to fix that by specifying the naming strategies, and using @Column.

The problem I have now is in the CrudRepository interface.

```
List<TableModel> findByRefNo(int RefNo);
```

The column name is 'RefNo', I have no control over this.

Hibernate keeps looking for 'refNo'

I suspect this is still a naming strategy issue.

How do I specify the column name in the interface?

Comment: You can use a @Query annotation with JPQL. Check  [Using @Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) from Spring official docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @Query annotation, I believe that will solve your problem. Like:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM TableModel m WHERE m.RefNo = ?1")
List<TableModel> findByRefNo(int RefNo);
```